# Bash: Associative array and its dynamic key names

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I'm a beginner to bash, and I'm quite struggling with associative array. I created many associative arrays and integrated all the data by using key '0, 1, 2, 3'. Simply saying `ArrayA[0], ArrayB[0], ArrayC[0]....` have data on a common topic. So these keys are important to me. Now I want to make another array to access these keys, and I want the keys of the new arrays to be the data of the related keys. For example,

```
declare -A NewArray
ArrayA[0]=3
ArrayB[0]=4
ArrayC[0]=6
NewArray[ArrayA[0]+ArrayB[0]+ArrayC[0]]=0
```

so that it could be `NewArray[346]=0` or `NewArray[3,4,6]=0`. Any helps would be  so much appreciated, I've been thinking about this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

Bash has no concatenation operator as it doesn't need any.

```
NewArray[${ArrayA[0]}${ArrayB[0]}${ArrayC[0]}]=0
echo ${NewArray[346]}
```

or

```
NewArray[${ArrayA[0]},${ArrayB[0]},${ArrayC[0]}]=0
echo ${NewArray[3,4,6]}
```